# How to get vimdiff to display output from cvs diff --side-by-side

Tags: vim, diff, cvs, vimdiff

CVS diff has the option to display revisions side by side and denote diffs with usual patch symbols like:

```
import zlib                                        import zlib
                                                 > import time
import traceback                                   import traceback

import cElementTree as ElementTree                 import cElementTree as ElementTree

from util import infopage                          from util import infopage
                                                 > from util.timeout import Timeout
```

Is there anyway to pipe that output to vimdiff so that it displays those two columns in two side-by-side buffers along with all the diff-highlighting goodness of vimdiff?

I'm aware of tools like cvsvimdiff.vim and the like, but the problem with those is that they only work on one file at a time, whereas the cvs diff output lists multiple files.

Comment: Could you tell which option of CVS does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have that text in a Vim buffer, you can easily split it into two buffers yourself.  Looks like your sample input does the split at 50 characters.

So use `<C-v>` to visual-block highlight half of the diff, cut it, paste it in a new buffer, remove trailing whitespace and the `>` separator characters, and there you go.  Or write a function to do it, something like this (which assumes the split is always at 50):

```
function! SplitCVSDiff()
    exe "norm gg_\<C-v>51\<Bar>Gd:vnew\<CR>p"
    silent! %s/\v\s+(\> )?$//
endfunction
```

Might have to be made more robust, I'm not familiar with the exact style of output CVS uses.  Shouldn't be hard though.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a script say : vimdiff_cvs file.cc
which does this:

1. Store diff of file.cc locally, delete it, update to repository. Now copy it as ~/.vimdiff/file.cc.repo.
2. Restorefile.cc by applying the patch
3. Call vimdiff file.cc ~/.vimdiff/file.cc.repo.